# Yahoo Finance API returns yesterday's data until after market closes

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I've been using Yahoo Finance queries for a few years now, and over the past weeks (or few months) I noticed that each query I try no longer returns 15-minute delayed data. Instead, while the market is open, it returns the prior market day's data (e.g. query run right now returns Tuesday's closing data). This is, based on my experience, new behavior.

For example, take this query:

[Get quote for S&P 500 Index](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol='%5EGSPC'&diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

When I ran it just a few minutes ago, the XML returned is:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2016-03-16T18:31:35Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<results>
<quote symbol="^GSPC">
<Ask>2017.27</Ask>
<AverageDailyVolume/>
<Bid>2010.86</Bid>
<AskRealtime/>
<BidRealtime/>
<BookValue>0.00</BookValue>
<Change_PercentChange>-3.71 - -0.18%</Change_PercentChange>
<Change>-3.71</Change>
<Commission/>
<Currency>USD</Currency>
<ChangeRealtime/>
<AfterHoursChangeRealtime/>
<DividendShare/>
<LastTradeDate>3/15/2016</LastTradeDate>
<TradeDate/>
<EarningsShare/>
<ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid/>
<EPSEstimateCurrentYear/>
<EPSEstimateNextYear/>
<EPSEstimateNextQuarter>0.00</EPSEstimateNextQuarter>
<DaysLow>2005.23</DaysLow>
<DaysHigh>2015.94</DaysHigh>
<YearLow>1810.10</YearLow>
<YearHigh>2134.72</YearHigh>
<HoldingsGainPercent/>
<AnnualizedGain/>
<HoldingsGain/>
<HoldingsGainPercentRealtime/>
<HoldingsGainRealtime/>
<MoreInfo/>
<OrderBookRealtime/>
<MarketCapitalization/>
<MarketCapRealtime/>
<EBITDA/>
<ChangeFromYearLow>205.83</ChangeFromYearLow>
<PercentChangeFromYearLow>+11.37%</PercentChangeFromYearLow>
<LastTradeRealtimeWithTime/>
<ChangePercentRealtime/>
<ChangeFromYearHigh>-118.79</ChangeFromYearHigh>
<PercebtChangeFromYearHigh>-5.56%</PercebtChangeFromYearHigh>
<LastTradeWithTime>4:05pm - <b>2015.93</b></LastTradeWithTime>
<LastTradePriceOnly>2015.93</LastTradePriceOnly>
<HighLimit/>
<LowLimit/>
<DaysRange>2005.23 - 2015.94</DaysRange>
<DaysRangeRealtime/>
<FiftydayMovingAverage/>
<TwoHundreddayMovingAverage/>
<ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage/>
<PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage/>
<ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage/>
<PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage/>
<Name>S&P 500</Name>
<Notes/>
<Open>2015.27</Open>
<PreviousClose>2019.64</PreviousClose>
<PricePaid/>
<ChangeinPercent>-0.18%</ChangeinPercent>
<PriceSales/>
<PriceBook/>
<ExDividendDate/>
<PERatio/>
<DividendPayDate/>
<PERatioRealtime/>
<PEGRatio>0.00</PEGRatio>
<PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear/>
<PriceEPSEstimateNextYear/>
<Symbol>^GSPC</Symbol>
<SharesOwned/>
<ShortRatio/>
<LastTradeTime>4:05pm</LastTradeTime>
<TickerTrend/>
<OneyrTargetPrice/>
<Volume>529043975</Volume>
<HoldingsValue/>
<HoldingsValueRealtime/>
<YearRange>1810.10 - 2134.72</YearRange>
<DaysValueChange/>
<DaysValueChangeRealtime/>
<StockExchange>SNP</StockExchange>
<DividendYield/>
<PercentChange>-0.18%</PercentChange>
</quote>
</results>
</query>
<!--  total: 16  -->
<!--  main-30546b49-eb09-11e5-80e5-ac162da43cf5  -->
```

Note the LastTradeTime value: 4:05pm
Also LastTradeDate value: 3/15/2016

This query was run today, March 16, 2016 at 11:31am PDT (note Yahoo timestamp from the XML header: yahoo:created="2016-03-16T18:31:35Z"). The volume, high, low, etc. all match yesterday's closing values. I see this for stocks, indices, ETF's, etc. Everything is old data until after the market closes.

This was not the case in the past, and I can find no documentation talking about this. Anybody know what is up?

Thanks!

Comment: I really don't know what is going on with these guys. Datatables.org which is their backend went down for over 24 hours yesterday and now the API is only returning data about 50% of the time

Comment: I am having similar issue for past 3 days...